# Let $X$ be a topology space . $A,B \subset X$ .Prove that $\bar{A}\bigcup \bar{B}=$ the closure of $A \bigcup B$ by some constructive approach .

Tags: general-topology

**My proof:**
Let $E$ denote the closure of $A \bigcup B$ , then it is clear that $\bar{A}\subset E$ and $\bar{B} \subset E$ . So we have $$\bar{A}\bigcup \bar{B} \subset E$$Also , $E$ is the smallest closed set contains $A \bigcup B$ , so we have $$E \subset \bar{A}\bigcup \bar{B}$$

The proof above is not constructive . For each $x\in E- (A\bigcup B) $ , I want to show $x \in \bar{A}-A$ or $x \in \bar{B}-B$ . If for every open set $U$ containing $x$ , we have $U \bigcap A$ nonempty , then $x \in \bar{A}-A$ and we are done. So assume there exist an open set $O$ containing $x$ such that $O \bigcap A=0$ , there exist another open set $V$ containing $x$ such that $V \bigcap B=0$ . This must lead to some contradiction , but I did not see how to show this .

Comment: I am not sure if trying a proof by contradiction is a good idea when looking fo a constructive proof as replacement for the first proof, of which I do not see why you don't accept it as constructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a standard inclusion proof of $\overline{A \cup B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$: that can only be done by a proof by contradiction (which is not very *constructive* in the philosphical sense): suppose $x \in E$ (i.e. the left hand side) and suppose (for a contradiction !) that $x \notin \overline{A}$. Then there is a neighbourhood $O_x$ of $x$ that misses $A$ entirely (this uses a (adherence point) characterisation of the closure, not its definition, another disadvantage of this approach) and let $V$ be any neighbourhood of $x$. Then $V \cap O_x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ so it intersects $A \cup B$, as $x \in \overline{A \cup B}$ and this point of intersection cannot be in $A$ as $O_x \cap A= \emptyset$ so $V \cap O_x$ and hence $V$, intersects $B$. So, as $V$ was arbitrary, $x \in \overline{B}$.

Alternatively we can assume $x \notin \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ so we have $x \notin \overline{A}$ and $x \notin \overline{B}$, giving two neighbourhoods $U_x$ and $V_x$ with $U_x \cap A=\emptyset$ and $V_x \cap B=\emptyset$ and then note that $$(U_x \cap V_x) \cap (A \cup B) \subseteq (U_x \cap A) \cup (V_x \cap B)= \emptyset$$

which is a contradiction with $x \in \overline{A \cup B}$. In effect you are proving a direct inclusion of the complements of the sets.

This proof is also common and more suitable when the closure of $A$ is defined as all points $x$ whose every neighbourhood intersects $A$, instead of the "smallest closed set that contains $A$", or equivalently, the intersection of all closed supersets of $A$. But the above proof assumes the former definition while my other proof starts from the second. So do you start with closure or closed sets...

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of what is *constructive* is not quite standard IMO.

That $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$ is indeed clear, as $A \subseteq A \cup B$ implies the same inclusion for the closures.

So $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$ is then direct and constructive (if $x$ is in either left hand set, it is in the right hand set).

That $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} $ is closed follows directly from the topology axioms. And as you define the closure of a set as the smallest closed set around it, $\overline{A \cup B}  \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} $ is immediate by that minimality and we have equality.
Nothing indirect or non-constructive. The two inclusions are the definition of equality in set theory.

Comment: I recognize this as a constructive proof.

Answer (score 0):

As a finite union of closed sets the set $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$
is closed and this with $A\cup B\subseteq\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$,
implying that: $$\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$$

Further we have $A\subseteq A\cup B\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$,
implying that $\overline{A}\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$.

Similarly we have  $B\subseteq A\cup B\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$,
implying that $\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$.

Combining this we find: $$\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$$

Proved is now that: $$\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$$

Comment: I think this proof is the same as my proof above . I want some constructive approach .

Comment: Then what do you mean by "constructive" in this context?

Comment: @J.Guo What you want is an indirect approach from a contradiction, **not** a constructive proof.

Comment: Indeed , I want to prove $A=B$ by the following way : For each $x \in A$ we have $x\in B$ .

Comment: IMO $A\subseteq B$ is just a (nice) "abbreviation" of "for each $x\in A$ we have $x\in B$".

Comment: @J.Guo You could try using nets.